# Go back to an instruction

Tags: c++

I was writing some code on C++, and I state that I am new in this language. In practice, after the instruction given in the if, I wrote a string indicating the user to write a new input. but when it inserts the variable for the second time, the program stops. Do you know how I could do? Ah, do you also know how to add the character to the user without needing to press enter?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  string line1 = "OOOOOO";
  string line2 = "OOIOOO";
  string line3 = "OOOOOO";
  string line4 = "OOOOOO";

  char I = 'I';
  char W = 'W';
  char A = 'A';
  char S = 'S';
  char D = 'D';

  char Input;

  cout << line1 << endl;
  cout << line2 << endl;
  cout << line3 << endl;
  cout << line4 << endl;

  cin >> Input;

  if (Input == D) {
    size_t found = line2.find(I);
    if (found != string::npos)
      line2[found] = 'O';
    line2[found + 1] = 'I';
    system("cls");

    cout << line1 << endl;
    cout << line2 << endl;
    cout << line3 << endl;
    cout << line4 << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "x: " << found << endl;
    cin >> Input;
  }
  if (Input == A) {
    size_t found = line2.find(I);
    if (found != string::npos)
      line2[found] = 'O';
    line2[found - 1] = 'I';
    system("cls");

    cout << line1 << endl;
    cout << line2 << endl;
    cout << line3 << endl;
    cout << line4 << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "x: " << found << endl;
    cin >> Input;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are only inserting A or D?

Comment: Yes, i did it. .

Comment: It's been a while since I used c/c++ but as far as I known, reading a single char from cin, the 2nd one is the EOL passed with the 1st

Comment: how could i fix it all?

Comment: I think you need a loop.
Because after second input there's nothing left to execute

Comment: can you please help me? i'm new

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  this  i have changed your if to while.
Now that will loop while your input is 'D'
If you input 'A' after 'D' it will execute both loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  string line1 = "OOOOOO";
  string line2 = "OOIOOO";
  string line3 = "OOOOOO";
  string line4 = "OOOOOO";

  char I = 'I';
  char W = 'W';
  char A = 'A';
  char S = 'S';
  char D = 'D';

  char Input;

  cout << line1 << endl;
  cout << line2 << endl;
  cout << line3 << endl;
  cout << line4 << endl;

  cin >> Input;

  while (Input == D) {
    size_t found = line2.find(I);
    if (found != string::npos)
      line2[found] = 'O';
    line2[found + 1] = 'I';
    system("cls");

    cout << line1 << endl;
    cout << line2 << endl;
    cout << line3 << endl;
    cout << line4 << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "x: " << found << endl;
    cin >> Input;
  }

while (Input == A) {
    size_t found = line2.find(I);
    if (found != string::npos)
      line2[found] = 'O';
    line2[found - 1] = 'I';
    system("cls");
    cout << line1 << endl;
    cout << line2 << endl;
    cout << line3 << endl;
    cout << line4 << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "x: " << found << endl;
    cin >> Input;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that you won't be able to press 'D' after pressing 'A'